# sort style css in angular

Tags: angular, css

I'm using Angular. I want to change the CSS specificity of the following webpage shown below:

[image: Picture of page with Chrome DevTools]

Specifically, I want to load 2 before 1. How can this be done?

Comment: What's the reason you want to do that?

Comment: In my project there are the same styles so I do it to change the priority

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is no way to change the order they're loaded. Instead, you'll have to make the selector for 2 more specific than 1

Comment: I can also solve it by using "!important", but i want to limit use "!important", So I post the question like that. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I Don't Understand Your Problem , you can put style 2 before style 1
or give style 2 !important , like this or problem is more Complex

Comment: I can also solve it by using "!important", but i want to limit use "!important"

Comment: Use Media Query For Second Style To All , If Not Solve tell me , I want to help you